# Quickblox session expiration while on background. How to handle it?

Tags: quickblox

When the user goes to background, I log out the user from chat. 
When the user comes back from background, I log the use again in chat.

This works well but not every time. Sometimes when the user keeps the app more then 2 hours in background, the session expires and it doesn't seem to revalidate automatically when the user comes back from background, even with this piece of code:

```
[QBSettings enableSessionExpirationAutoHandler:YES];
```

Should the app revalidate the session/QB login automatically with enableSessionExpirationAutoHandler  on even when coming from background?

Is there another way to handle session expiration while in background? Can anyone please suggest me some ideas?

Comment: If the answer has worked for you please mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any session will remain valid for 2 hours after the last request to QuickBlox. To check a session's expiration date use this next snippet of code:

```
NSDate *sessionExpiratioDate = [QBBaseModule sharedModule].tokenExpirationDate;
```

Check this guide http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#A_couple_of_words_about_Authentication_and_Authorization

This feature is available since 1.8 iOS SDK

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Framework_changelog:

Comment: Thanks Igor, but what I would like to know is if [QBSettings enableSessionExpirationAutoHandler:YES]; is enough or do I need to manage session expiration?

Comment: You can use it, but this an old and undocumented feature and could be changed in future. I recommend to manually manage session expiration.
For example do this each time in delegate method applicationWillEnterForeground

Comment: Thanks. Will do that.