# How to manage Quick Blox Session?

Tags: ios, objective-c, session, quickblox

I have a question regarding Quick blox API. Right now I am sign up an user using below code.

```
 [QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {
            // session created

            QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
            user.password = userPasswordTextField.text;
            user.login = userNameTextField.text;
            user.fullName = userRealNameTextField.text;
            user.email = userEmailTextField.text;

            // Registration sign up of User
            [QBRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {

                [QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {
                    NSLog(@"checkingl registering");
                    [QBRequest userWithLogin:user.login successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
                        NSLog(@"checkingl updatingqb");

                    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
                        // Handle error
                    }];

                }errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
                    // Handle error
                }];

            } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
                // Handle error here
                NSLog(@"error while signing up with QB");

                NSLog(@"fail sign Up %@",response);;

                [self showAlert:nil message:@"User with login that has already been taken" cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitle:@"OK"];


                return ;

            }];
        } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
            // handle errors
            NSLog(@" error in creating session %@", response.error);
        }];
```

In above code first I am creating a session and sign up an new user, then I am login user. At sign up time I did't log in user for QuickBlox Chat at signup time, But later when I will log in into Quick blox chat  in another module, still I have to create new session or I have to maintain new session.

Comment: You'r asking what to when starting chat??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388204/forced-to-create-a-new-quickblox-session-every-time-ios-app-is-opened  saad please check I have similar doubt.

Comment: Naeem answers seems perfect. Lemme know if it don't works I'll download my code from repo and will let you know How I managed this issue. It was some sort of same as Naeem has written

Comment: @007 If answer worked for you than you can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any session will remain valid for 2 hours after the last request to QuickBlox. To check a session's expiration date use this next snippet of code:

```
NSDate *sessionExpiratioDate = [QBBaseModule sharedModule].tokenExpirationDate;
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval interval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:tokenExpirationDate];
if(interval > 0){
  // recreate session here
}
```

Check [this](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#A_couple_of_words_about_Authentication_and_Authorization) guide. [This](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Framework_changelog) feature is available since 1.8 iOS SDK.

Reference: [Igor Khomenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21257143/3859370)

Comment: Thanks Naeem But I saw this link.Ok You mean later I have to use this session, and after two hour I have create newone

Comment: Yes you have to recreate session.

Comment: Hi I fetched remaining time of Quick blox session and I alos ignored creating session if session time is exist but againg login into chat my code is getting crashed. I am getting this ar 2108443
2014-12-22 18:00:40.651 OClub[4587:5507] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'BaseServiceException', reason: 'You have missed the authorization call.
Please insert following code inside your application 
[QBAuth createSessionWithDelegate:self];

Comment: hey Thanks Naeem Actually I have already seen this think but you built up my Confidence :D

Comment: I am glad that I built up your confidence. Btw your problem solved or not?